# SQL Group By Before Averaging

Tags: sql, ms-access, average

Currently I have a query that finds the average of points scored depending upon opponent.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT NBAGameLog.Opp, AVG(NBAGameLog.Points)
FROM Players INNER JOIN
     NBAGameLog
     ON Players.Player_ID = NBAGameLog.Player_ID
WHERE (NBAGameLog.Date_Played Between Date()-15 And Date() AND
      Players.Position = "C"
GROUP BY NBAGameLog.Opp;
```

The issue happens if I have something like this:

NBAGameLog table:

```
Player_ID    Team     Opp     Points     Position
1            MIA      ATL     15         C
2            MIA      ATL     25         C
3            BOS      ATL     23         C
```

The result from this would be:

```
Position       Opp       Average
C              ATL       21
```

But I'd like the query to first group together the Teams. So instead of (15+25+23)/3, it would see that the first two players were on the same team, so only count that as one and do (40+23)/2

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a subquery, aggregating first in the subquery then again in the outer query:

```
SELECT t.Opp, avg(Points)
FROM (SELECT gl.team, gl.Opp, AVG(gl.Points) as Points
      FROM Players p INNER JOIN
           NBAGameLog gl
           ON p.Player_ID = gl.Player_ID
      WHERE (gl.Date_Played Between Date()-15 And Date() AND
            p.Position = "C"
     GROUP BY gl.team, gl.Opp;
    ) t
GROUP BY t.Opp;
```

Comment: This was very close. The only problem was that I needed to change the AVG in the subquery to SUM. Got me on the right track though, thanks!

Comment: @fullOfQuestions . . . If you use `sum()`, then the example in the question would be (40+23)/2 = 31.  I chose `avg()` because it seemed to get closer to the OP value.